# Jasper reports Parameter Form

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Im pretty new to *JasperReport Server*. I have had success using *JasperReport Sever 4.7*(Community edition) and calling jasper reports (using jasperviewer)from within a java application.

My problem is:
1. To create my own parameter form which pops up when a user clicks a button linking to a jasper report.

1. User to be able to enters the desired parameters (preferably selectable from a list) then when the user presses enter or ok on this page, it passes the values to the jasper report accordingly.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, when you create your report and save in your **Jasper repository** -

1. Just right-clik the report folder (the one containing your Main.jrxml) and click on `Properties`. A dialog box appears.
2. Go to `Other` tab. Next to `Controls Layout` label there will be a drop-down box. Select `Pop-up Screen` on that. Your job is done.

For the second, you can definitely have a select list. There are two ways to generate values for the list - by using a query or entering manually. The steps are:

1. In your report folder in the repository, under your main.jrxml file there will be an `Input Controls` folder. Right click on it and click on `Create a local input control`. A dialog box will appear.
2. On the `General` tab give the ID and name for the input control (ID must match to your respective parameter name).
3. Go to `Input Control Details` tab. Select type as "Single Select Query" or "Single Select List of Values" as per your requirements. Enter the query or values and your job is done.

Comment: Thanks. I have done just that and it runs well. My Problem now is I'm using Jdeveloper to create an ADF application. I have successfully been able to call jasperreports using a java class (no jasperver involved) and render the report using jasperviewer. I would now like to create a parameter form for my reports without having to use jasperserver. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this. I have no idea.